# $\sqrt{4x -3}$ injective? Bijective? Inverse?

Tags: functions, inverse

I'm shown part of the function $g(x) = \sqrt{4x-3}$. Is it injective? I said yes as per definition if $f(x) = f(y)$, then $x =y$. Is this right?

Under what criteria is $g(x)$ bijective? For what domain and co domain does $g(x)$ meet this criteria? I'm totally lost on this one!

Find the inverse of $g(x)$, sketch the graph and explain how $g(x)$ and $g^{-1}(x)$ relate geometrically.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: For a function to be bijective, it must be both injective and surjective.  You have shown it is injective.  To be surjective, the codomain must be equal to the range.  Therefore, you must find the range of $f(x) = \sqrt{4x - 3}$ to determine the codomain that will make the function surjective.

Answer (score 1):

It really makes no sense to ask whether a function is surjective if you don't have the codomain.

That is: you have something like $f(x)=\sqrt{4x-3}$. If you are working with real numbers, $x$ must be $\ge\frac34$ in order to the square root makes sense. Furthermore, the values that takes $f(x)$ are nonnegative.

So we can, in most cases, assume that the domain of $f$ is "as greatest as possible"; in this case, $[\frac34,\infty)$. But a function is not only an expression and a domain. It's a codomain, too.

The codomain is the set in which the values of $f$ lie. But this set can have more elements that $f$ never reaches.

For example: for our $f(x)=\sqrt{4x-3}$, we can set $f:[\frac34,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ and if $f$ is defined this way, $f$ is surjective. Because any element from $[0,\infty)$ (this is the codomain) is reached by $f$.

But if we set $f:[\frac34,\infty)\to\Bbb R$, then $f$ is not surjective, because $f$ does never take negative values.

Answer (score 0):

A function is bijective if it is surjective and injective. A function is surjective if the range is the codomain, i.e. if every value in the codomain is the output of the function.

An inverse function is the function reflected trough $y=x$.